# Understanding the argument values for mdptoolbox forest example

Tags: python, numpy, reinforcement-learning, mdptoolbox

I am trying to understand how to use [mdptoolbox](https://pymdptoolbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/example.html) and had a few questions.

What does `20` mean in the following statement?

```
P, R = mdptoolbox.example.forest(10, 20, is_sparse=False)
```

I understand that `10` here denotes the number of possible states. What does `20` mean here? Does it represent the total number of actions per state? I want to restrict the MDP to exactly 2 actions per state. How could I do this?

The shape of `P` returned above is `(2, 10, 10)`. What does `2` represent here? No matter what values I use for total states and actions, it is always `2`.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation?

Comment: @roganjosh Yes, I have also shared the link in the question. But still had confusions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code which you are running is correct, but what you are using is an example from the toolbox.

Please go through the [documentation](https://pymdptoolbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/example.html) carefully.

In the following code:

`P, R = mdptoolbox.example.forest(10, 20, is_sparse=False)`

The second argument is not an action-argument for the MDP. [Its documentation](https://pymdptoolbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/example.html#mdptoolbox.example.forest) explains the second argument as follows:

> The reward when the forest is in its oldest state and action ‘Wait’ is performed. Default: 4.

In your case, the value of the reward is passed as `20` when the forest is in the oldest state and the action `Wait` is performed.

In case of this example, the forest is managed by two actions: `‘Wait’` and `‘Cut’`. Please refer this [documentation](https://pymdptoolbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/example.html#mdptoolbox.example.forest) for more details. Since, 2 actions possible, the transition probability matrix `P` returned by this function is also having the first dimension size as `2`. You do not need to manually restrict the action space dimension to `2`.

To understand the use of this toolbox, you should also go through [this link](https://pymdptoolbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mdp.html).

Comment: Okay, so the two actions `wait` and `cut` are the 2 available actions per state?

Comment: Yes, these 2 actions are available per state.

Comment: When I keep the number of states as `2`, the probability matrix shape is (2,2,2) and looks like https://pasteboard.co/Iiv9YTB.png . I cannot understand this output and relate it to the reward matrix returned which looks like https://pasteboard.co/Iivaxfp.png . Could you please explain?

Comment: Your reward matrix is of the dimension `(state_size, action_size)`, i.e., reward received when you take an action in a state. It gives you the output for the reward `r(i, j)` for the  `(state_i, action_j)`. You have `2 states` and `2 actions`, hence the `(2, 2)` reward matrix `R`.

For state transition you get the `action_size` matrices of dimensions `(state_size, state_size)`. Therefore, the dimensions of matrix `P` are `(action_size, state_size, state_size)`. That is after taking `action_i` in `state_j`, possibility of going from `state_j` to `state_k`.